# 'Email a Link' uses the renamed URL which fails

Tags: document-library, url, alternate-access-mapping, library

I have a SharePoint server which was originally named http://sharepoint2.xyz.com.  I setup an AAM so that our users use http://sharepoint.xyz.com.  And then later SSL was added so all users go to https://sharepoint.xyz.com to get to their site.  My zones are Default which is http://sharepoint2.xyz.com, Internet which is http://sharepoint.xyz.com and Custom which is https://sharepoint.xyz.com.  The Internal URLS are the same as the Public URLs.  All is fine everywhere else except yesterday it was discovered that when a user tries to 'Email a Link' of a document or a library, the URL starts with http://sharepoint2.xyz.com rather than https://sharepoint.xyz.com and if you try to follow the URL, it fails with the "webpage cannot be found".

Is this a situation where I need to use Updatealert with Stsadm even though it's not an alert as such or is SharePoint getting this from somewhere else?

Update:  All links in the Alert Me messages are fine.  I can't figure this out.

Appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fwiw - if you aren't using the sharepoint2 url any longer and are only keeping it around for legacy purposes, then you should probably make http://sharepoint.xyz.com as your default URL and set SharePoint2 as an AAM for the default zone.  Assuming that your default zone and Internet zone use the same authentication, that is!  This isn't a solution to your problem but it might make other things easier down the road.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  Should https be the default URL or the insecure one?

Comment: I generally use the http address for the default and then list the https address as the primary for one of the other zones, like Internet or Extranet.